# Suspicious URLs being hit? Should I use Cloudflare or similar service?

Tags: web-application

I checked my request logs and observed that URLs that seem suspicious are being hit.

Should I increase the security of my application using Cloudflare or block the IP addresses from where I am receiving these hits? Or are these hit by bots?

URLs from my request logs:

```
https://<my_ip_address>/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?type=rau
https://<my_ip_address>/owa/auth/logon.aspx?url=https%3a%2f%2f1%2fecp%2f
https://<my_ip_address>/login/companyInfo/seriously
https://<my_website_url>/cron/.env
https://<my_ip_address>/.well-known/security.txt
```

Comment: These are probably bots, scanning websites to look for security vulnerabilities a hacker could exploit

Comment: thanks @yeah22 how threatening are these ? should I do something to make my application more secure?

Comment: Welcome to the Internet. They are only threatening if your server is vulnerable to what they are testing for..

Comment: @Nikhil Singh if your application is secure, then don't worry about it